# Get processes that use the network

Tags: powershell

Are there any good methods that allow to get processes using the network? I did not find such parameters in `Get-Process` or `Get-Counter`. Therefore, at the moment, I extracted the id from `NetStat` and looked in `Get-Process`:

```
$Id = (NetStat -Ano).Where({ $_ -match "LISTENING|ESTABLISHED" }).ForEach({ $_.Split(' ')[-1] }) | Select -Unique

(Get-Process -Id $Id).Path
```

But surely there is a special simple method for this. Thanks

**Edited** Using @Lieven Keersmaekers’s hint ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60380252/get-processes-that-use-the-network?noredirect=1#comment106817510_60380252)), I did this way:

```
$Id = (Get-NetTCPConnection -AppliedSetting Internet).OwningProcess | Select -Unique

(Get-Process -Id $Id).Path
```

Comment: I've toyed with this as well.  The only other solution I've found and used (but can't seem to find the code right now), was to P/Invoke getting the process information for the ports.

Comment: You can use `Get-NetTCPConnection`. Note that this requires powershell 5.1